# Adding an ISO to GRUB2 boot options

Tags: ubuntu, grub, iso-image, fdisk

I am trying to add an ISO (alternate distro of ubuntu ) to my GRUB .

This is the output of `fdisk -l`:

---

> FDISK OUTPUT

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00061b6d
```

```
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        9539    76614656   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            9539        9730     1533953    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            9539        9730     1533952   82  Linux swap / Solaris

 

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x41ffc810
 
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       30401   244196001    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

---

> grub.cfg

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Alternate Install 10.10 32bit" {
 loopback loop (hd0,0)/boot/ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.iso
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/boot/ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.iso noprompt nomodeset 
 initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

I added an entry to 40_custom file like this  and did a sudo grub-update.

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Alternate Install 10.10 32bit" {
 loopback loop (hd0,1)/boot/ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.iso
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/boot/ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.iso noprompt nomodeset 
 initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```

But I am getting this File Not Found , You need to load kernel etc when I chose this option from the GRUB Menu .
Where am I going wrong

Comment: Did you try giving your new menuentry a different name than the one in grub.cfg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg you have to leave out the **(hd0,1)**:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop ISO" {
 loopback loop /ubuntu.iso
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso noeject noprompt splash --
 initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

This can be found at [Boot Multiple ISO from USB via Grub2 unsing Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/). Probably you should check out this page and compare these steps with your setup.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get a community wiki going on these topics, I'll just copy my answer from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/199433/useful-custom-grub-entries) below. I hope this helps!

---

So I have created a simple file `39_iso` inside `/etc/grub.d/` for loading my ISO's. I have a copy of Ubuntu 10.10, Clonezilla, and SystemRescueCD. My entries make sure the ISO file is available inside `/iso/` before adding the menu entry. For example Clonezilla will load into memory, so I can clone my hard drive whenever I want!

Ubuntu 10.10:

```
if test -e /iso/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso ; then
  isofile="/iso/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
  echo "Found Ubuntu 10.10 (x64) ISO: ${isofile}" >&2
  cat << EOF

  menuentry "Ubuntu 10.10 (x64) ISO"
  {
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
  }
EOF
fi
```

Clonezilla:

```
if test -e /iso/clonezilla-live-1.2.6-24-amd64.iso ; then
  isofile="/iso/clonezilla-live-1.2.6-24-amd64.iso"
  echo "Found Clonezilla Live ISO: ${isofile}" >&2
  cat << EOF

  menuentry "Clonezilla Live 1.2.6-24-amd64 ISO"
  {
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live live-config union=aufs nolocales noprompt ocs_lang="en_US.UTF-8" ocs_live_keymap="NONE" vga=791 ip=frommedia toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
  }
EOF
fi
```

SystemRescueCD

```
if test -e /iso/systemrescuecd-x86-1.6.2.iso ; then
  isofile="/iso/systemrescuecd-x86-1.6.2.iso"
  echo "Found SystemRescueCD ISO: ${isofile}" >&2
  cat << EOF

  menuentry "SystemRescueCD 1.6.2 (x64) ISO"
  {
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/isolinux/rescue64 setkmap=us docache isoloop=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initram.igz
  }
EOF
fi
```

---

I've also fixed how GRUB names Windows 7 as `Windows 7 (loader)` to something nicer like `Windows 7 Professional (x64)`:

```
if [ "${LONGNAME}" = "Windows 7 (loader)" ] ; then
  LONGNAME="Windows 7 Professional (x64)"
elif [ -z "${LONGNAME}" ] ; then
  LONGNAME="${LABEL}"
fi
```

It replaced a section such as the following:

```
if [ -z "${LONGNAME}" ] ; then
  LONGNAME="${LABEL}"
fi
```

Inside `30_os-proper` of GRUB